# Does OJDBC support Oracle Hints in Prepared Statements

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, ojdbc

I have a query like this:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM " + table.getName().quoted() + " WHERE modificationTime < ? AND ROWNUM < " + (objectsPerCommit + 1);
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setObject(1, ...timestamp_value..., ...timestamp_type...);
boolean result = statement.execute();
...
statement.close();
```

So the SQL I execute basically is:

```
  DELETE
  FROM
    mytable 
  WHERE
    modificationTime < to_date('2014-06-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    AND ROWNUM <= 10000;
```

This query runs *very very* slow, because it does not make use of an existing combined index over modificationTime and two other columns. Instead it does a full table scan.
If I force the usage of said index with a hint as demonstrated below everything runs smoothly.

```
  DELETE /*+ index(mytable PK_MYTABLE) */
  FROM
    mytable 
  WHERE
    modificationTime < to_date('2014-06-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    AND ROWNUM <= 10000;
```

My question is: does this work over OJDBC? Can I simply change the code to:

```
String sql = "DELETE /*+ index(mytable PK_MYTABLE) */ FROM " + table.getName().quoted() + " WHERE modificationTime < ? AND ROWNUM < " + (objectsPerCommit + 1);
...
```

and everything works as expected? Or will OJDBC somehow drop the comment/hint?

Comment: Just try - what's the problem?

Comment: I think the OP want to know if it will work in fact or will be disconsidered by the prepared statement as a simple comment.

Comment: `HINTS` are database specific. Also, `/*+ */` are enclosed in double quotes, so the client doesn't ignore it. But for _bind_ variables, _no_ part of `SQL` could be retouched by the client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. Hints are supported > http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/instclnt.htm#JJDBC28224

Comment: Note that linked article is in the context of JDBC OCI drivers, not JDBC THIN drivers.